# Overwrite DB with a SELECT

Tags: sqlite, perl

I'm trying to replace an entire table with a SELECT statement and I'm not sure how to delete all the data in the table then replace it with the correct data.

I've been trying to use the fetchall_arrayref but cannot figure it out on how I can put the data into an array and then refill the table with the SELECT data

So I've got

```perl
my $st = $dbh->prepare ("SELECT source, group_concat(port, ' ') AS ports FROM probes GROUP BY source");
my $rv = $st->execute() or die "Error;;;;";
```

and

```perl
my $data;
foreach $data ( @$data) {
    (my $variable1, my $variable2) = @$data;


}
```

I'm just trying to take the grouped SELECT data from $st and replace the entire table with it.

Answer (score 1):

You should be doing this in two steps.  First, delete or truncate the target table.  Then, do an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` using your current select logic:

```
DELETE FROM yourTable;

INSERT INTO yourTable
SELECT source, GROUP_CONCAT(port, ' ')
FROM probes
GROUP BY source;
```

Comment: Are you talking about doing something like this? 
```perl
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO probes (source, port) VALUES(?,?)
       SELECT source, group_concat(port, ' ') 
       AS ports FROM probes GROUP BY source");
```

Comment: No, I'm not, because that suggestion won't actually delete anything.

Comment: Yes I know but how would I get INSERT and SELECT onto the same line is what I'm not understanding.